# Why does random.sample() add square brackets and single quotes to the item sampled?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, random

I'm trying to sample an item (which is one of the keys in a dictionary) from a list and later use the index of that item to find its corresponding value (in the same dictionary).

```
questions= list(capitals.keys())
answers= list(capitals.values())
for q in range(10):
    queswrite = random.sample(questions,1)
    number = questions.index(queswrite)
    crtans = answers[number]
```

Here,capitals is the original dectionary from which the states(keys) and capitals(values) are being sampled.

But,apparently random.sample() method adds square brackets and single quotes to the sampled item and thus prevents it from being used to reference the list containing the corresponding values.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "F:\test.py", line 30, in
>
> number = questions.index(queswrite)
>
> ValueError: ['Delaware'] is not in list

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

`random.sample()` returns a *list*, containing the number of elements you requested. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a *k* length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

If you wanted to pick just *one* element, you don't want a sample however, you wanted to choose just one. For that you'd use the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
question = random.choice(questions)
```

However, given that you are using a loop, you probably really wanted to get *10 unique questions*. Don't use a loop over `range(10)`, instead pick a sample of 10 random questions. That's exactly what `random.sample()` would do for you:

```
for question in random.sample(questions, 10):
    # pick the answer for this question.
```

Next, putting both keys and values into two separate lists, then using the index of one to find the other is... inefficient and unnecessary; the keys you pick can be used *directly* to find the answers:

```
questions = list(capitals)
for question in random.sample(questions, 10):
    crtans = capitals[question]
```